# jquery: check radio button by value after load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check a radio-button by value after I've loaded the radio buttons into a div with the JQuery load() function.

Problem:
I cannot check the radio button by value. When executing the line code in the console it works.

```
$(document).on("click", "#g1q2back", function() {
  // empty div
  $(".hero").empty();
  // load other content into div
  $('.hero').load("./pages/g1q1.html");
  // set radiobutton by value 3
  $("input[name=question1][value=" + 3 + "]").attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Comment: `if ($('input[name="question1"]')[0].value === '3') { $('input[name="question1"]')[0].checked = true`

Comment: Please be aware that `checked` is a property of an element. You may also want to execute that code in a callback function from load to ensure it is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code.

```
$(document).on("click", "#g1q2back", function() {
  $(".hero").empty().load("./pages/g1q1.html", function(){
    $("input[name='question1'][value='3']").prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

Please see: https://api.jquery.com/load/